# How to get the integer number of PathItems? (Illustrator Script)

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I created a code to apply a random color to a path on Illustrator. However, it only applies to the first path of the layer, ignoring my selection. I know it happens because pathItems[] is 0. If it is 1, it recolorizes the second path, and so on.

How can I find out the integer number of the my current selection? So I can store it as a "AnyNumber" variable and replace docRef.pathItems[0] with docRef.pathItems[ANYNUMBER].

Reference of PathItems [here](https://illustrator-scripting-guide.readthedocs.io/jsobjref/PathItems/).

Thank you.

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;


// Create color

var rgb; 
var rgb = new RGBColor();

var random1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
var random2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
var random3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);

rgb.red = random1;
rgb.green = random2;
rgb.blue = random3;


// Create swatch

var swatch = docRef.swatches.add();

swatch.color = rgb;

swatch.name = "Random Color"; 


// Apply swatch

var pathRef = docRef.pathItems[0];

pathRef.filled = true;

pathRef.fillColor = swatch.color;

pathRef.stroked = false;


// Delete swatch

swatchToDelete = app.activeDocument.swatches[swatch.name];

swatchToDelete.remove();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by creating an array.

Here is the whole script, if someone in the future wants to check the code:

```
doc = app.activeDocument;
sel = app.activeDocument.selection;
selSwatch = doc.swatches.getSelected();

if (sel instanceof Array) {

    if(selSwatch.length != 0)

        for (i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {

            if(sel[i].typename == "PathItem" || sel[i].typename == "CompoundPathItem") {

                selobj = sel[i];
                selobj.filled = true;

                // Create color

                var rgb;
                var rgb = new RGBColor();

                var random1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
                var random2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
                var random3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);

                rgb.red = random1;
                rgb.green = random2;
                rgb.blue = random3;

                // Create swatch

                var swatch = doc.swatches.add();

                swatch.color = rgb;

                swatch.name = "Random Color"; 

                // Apply swatch

                selobj.filled = true;

                selobj.stroked = false;

                selobj.fillColor = swatch.color;


                // Delete swatch

                swatchToDelete = doc.swatches[swatch.name];

                swatchToDelete.remove();

}}}
```